# What is meant by the steady-state activation of a receptor?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, cell-signaling

I am reading a [journal paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5513484/) about the insulin-like growth factor 1 receptor. In this paper, there is the following statement:

> Finally, we show that the IGF-IR and the PI3K subunit p85 and Akt are
> detected in cholesterol-rich membrane domains under conditions of
> steady-state IGF-IR activation and that phosphorylated Akt and IGF-IR
> are detected in CEMs with IGF-I stimulation.

I am not sure what is meant by the *"steady-state activation"* of the IGF-IR receptor. I have searched the definition of steady-state with regards to proteins and I have read the [following](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3654667/#:%7E:text=The%20%27steady%20state%27%20is%20defined,the%20concentration%20of%20this%20protein.):

> The ‘steady state’ is defined by a zero net change of a parameter in a
> system. For example, the abundance of a protein might not vary during
> the time of observation because rates of translation and degradation
> are balanced. The cell is said to be at the steady state with respect
> to the concentration of this protein.

However, in the context of this paper, I don't this is what steady-state refers to since they are talking about the activation not levels of the receptor.

Does anyone know what is meant by the steady-state activation of a receptor? I think it refers to the activation that occurs without any exogenous stimulation (e.g. addition of insulin/IGF-1 to cells). Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the Methods section of the paper? That's where you'd find this information. It's possible they mean what you guess, but I'd expect that to be called baseline or constitutive activity or something like that instead; still, the best source is the methods section.

Comment: As mentioned above, it is best to check with Method or a reference paper.
One method might be to introduce mutations in the kinase domain of IGF-1R, thereby constantly increasing kinase activity.
Other possible methods include overexpression of the IGF-1R gene to increase the number of IGF-1R receptors in the cell and enhance signaling, deletion of genes for inhibitor proteins that regulate IGF-1R or genes that negatively regulate signaling.